# Equivalence but not congruence

Tags: coq

All

I'm working on sf/plf chapter Equiv. There is an exercise

> We've shown that the [cequiv] relation is both an equivalence and a congruence on commands. Can you think of a relation on commands that is an equivalence but *not* a congruence?

I do not quite understand the difference between equivalence and congruence.
It seems both behavioral equivalence of a program.
Can any one explain more about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other equivalences than "behavioral equivalence". An equivalence is any relation which is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. A congruence is a structure-preserving equivalence.

A common example for an equivalence which is a congruence is arithmetic modulo n. Equality say modulo 10 is an equivalence relation which preserves addition and multiplication, so it is a congruence for the integer ring arithmetic. But it is not a congruence e.g. for "round to 0 integer division". E.g. `23/11=2` but `3/1=3`, that is `23 mod 10 = 3 mod 10` and `11 mod 10 = 1 mod 10`, but `23/11 mod 10 <> 3/1 mod 10`.